# Android: Application still running after call finish()

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

I'm new at Android Development...

I create a new activity and call `finish();` method. But it still running, consuming battery, memory...
[image: Battery and memory consumption after activity is destroyed]

Is there a way of stop the application completely, avoiding battery and memory consumption after activity is destroyed?

Comment: The system will reclaim the memory if it deems that necessary, it will otherwise keep the resources loaded because it's quicker in case the user comes back. It's also not really consuming anything. Free memory is wasted memory. Good use of memory is when there are relevant items still cached. Battery consumption is only caused by CPU activity, which won't happen unless you have a running thread that outlives an activity. Don't try to break that by killing your app process or by using "memory cleaner" apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicated Question!
**You can't control when your app leaves the main memory, the OS does. Look closely at** [Activity.finish()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#finish%28%29)
I think there will be no way of stopping the application completely, avoiding battery and memory consumption after the activity is destroyed.
Answer(Link) is  :
[Activity.finish() called but activity stays loaded in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594996/activity-finish-called-but-activity-stays-loaded-in-memory)

Answer (score 0):

finish method just finish the intent! If you want to exit from app then use

`system.exit(0);`

Comment: This stop the profile windown on Android Studio... But my application still appearing on my battery and memory manager...

Comment: Do you make any service in your app?

Comment: may be try this finishAffinity();
    System.exit(0);

Comment: It is recommended not to use `System.exit(0);`, see for example [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32924802/why-one-should-not-use-system-exit0-in-android-application)

Comment: ~Siamak Ferdos: There isn't any service on app.
~Nik: finishAffinity() requires `mimAppLevel` 16, and my is 15...
~ 0X0nosugar: `System.exit(0)` don't solve the problem, so I will remove it...

Comment: Any chance other code getting executed after you issue `finish()`?  [ `finish()` is non-immediate. I usually follow it with `return` ]